# Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.9.3-p551 gemset_pristine'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

On Mac OS X 10.10 yosemite, I am trying to reinstall `ruby-1.9.3-p551` using RVM and I am getting this problem. I am just not sure how to tackle this or if the error is important to address.

```
$ rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p551 

ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p551..
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p551 to /Users/joel/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551....
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /Users/joel/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #configuring...............................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #compiling...................................................................................................................................................|
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #installing...........
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #making binaries executable..
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading rubygems-2.4.6
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting rubygems-2.4.6.....
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing old rubygems.........
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #installing rubygems-2.4.6.....................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #gemset created /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #importing gemset /Users/joel/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems...........................................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #gemset created /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/joel/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #generating default wrappers........
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #complete 
WARNING: Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that is no longer maintained (2014-02-23), for a list of maintained rubies visit:

    http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ReleaseEngineering

Please consider upgrading to ruby-2.2.0 which will have all of the latest security patches.
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p551 pristine..........................................................
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.9.3-p551 gemset_pristine',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/joel/.rvm/log/1424174694_ruby-1.9.3-p551/gemset.pristine-ruby-1.9.3-p551.log
++ _failed+=("${_gem} --version ${_version}")
++ read _gem _version _platforms
++ ((  1 > 0  ))
++ rvm_error '\n'\''command gem pristine --extensions  --version '\'' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.'
++ rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b '\n'\''command gem pristine --extensions  --version '\'' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.\n'

'command gem pristine --extensions  --version ' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.
++ return 1
++ return 1
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p551@global pristine..........................................................
```

Any pointers are welcome.